# editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY) is not working for Galaxy S II

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Is there any way in Android to display the numeric soft keyboard when focusing on and EditText, but still allow any text to be entered?

I have tried using the below code, but it is not working for Galaxy S II, Galaxy Tab, etc.

`editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY)`

Is there a trick to this working for all devices?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

need to set `android:inputType="number"` on `EditText` property.

It works for me.

Let me know

Comment: In this case, i couldn't able to enter text. for example, i need to enter values as like this : 123112abc,12312aaa.. How can i achieve this?

Comment: try using multiple options like number|text

Comment: Thanks Mithesh. will check and let you know.